# Removing rows marked for DELETE - DBF files - SQL

Tags: sql, dbf

I have thousands of ***individual*** **DBF** files that contain lines marked for deletion. I'm trying to find a way to permanently remove all of these marked entries in a quick fashion. I've scoured the web and am struggling to find anything noteworthy and/or helpful. Would anyone happen to have any suggestions?

Comment: How are you accessing the dbf files? Foxpro uses the pack command, and I suspect Clipper and dBase have similar commands.

Answer (score 0):

Just run PACK TABLE or REINDEX TABLE

Comment: And why would that help?